# UIScrollView and detecting gestures of its subview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have ImageView inside ScrollView, to provide zooming. There are a few subview within ImageView, which must be draggable. Problem is that ScrollView blocked gestures of its subviews. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it. So, first of all, you need to create a delegate that will send message to ScrollView to disable scrolling, when you touched the subviews which want to drag, and enable scrolling when you let go it. And thereafter set the exclusiveTouch property of the ImageView to YES.